# How to modify a web.config from Powershell in a SharePoint web service deployed through a wsp

Tags: web-services, powershell, sharepoint-2010

Here is my situation:
I have a third party webservice (.asmx) that is deployed in SharePoint 2010, through a WSP. This all works just fine. Part of the deployed files is a web.config which sits in the same folder as the .asmx (_vti_bin/somefolder/).

Up to this point, the web.config could always be exactly the same for each environment (dev, test, prod). We have now reached a point where we need to include information specific for the environment, namely the domain name is different for each environment and we'd like to grant access to this webservice for only one account.

As we are already deploying everything through Powershell, we'd like to use this for changing this setting in the web.config.

To clarify, I know how to do changes in the SharePoint web.config from Powershell, but not how to make changes to this separate web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you couldn't use something such as this ?

```
$xml.Load($CONFIG_FILE);
$conString = ($xml.configuration.connectionStrings.add | ? {$_.name -eq "DBContext"})
$conString.connectionString = "..."
$xml.Save($CONFIG_FILE)
```